# Testing WML documents without Nokia

Tags: testing, wap, wml

Are there any testing platforms out there for testing WAP/WML pages besides that provided by Nokia? I have tried to get ahold of the Nokia Mobile Internet Toolkit but it's too tied down with authentication and certificates etc.

Nokia software is like Adobe and......sucks.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really wap-oriented, but Aptana does have a plugin for symbian widgets, which I think is mostly html.

Answer (score 0):

Openwave used to do an SDK for this purpose, which was very useful for testing compatibility with the large number of mobile phones shipped with Openwave Mobile Browsers. Since Openwave sold off their browser business it is no longer available on their websites or those of their successors - they appear to have deleted all the developer support information.

But a Google search for "Openwave SDK" may help.